# How to convert the function output to a variable of type float (php) for further mathematical operations?

Tags: php, function, variables, types

**Hello php developers, please help the beginner!**
 - **I sincerely thank you for your help**

*Function code:*

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
    // get info about the request
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    $arr = json_decode($data,true);
    $c = array_map( function ($in){
        return  $in['ask']['c'];
    }, $arr['candles']);
    sort($c);
    //echo 'Min is: '.current($c)."\n";
    $fin = end($c);
    $float = (float)$fin;
    var_dump($float);
```

output: `var_dump($float);
 float(1.20383)`

*My code:*

```
function pivoty()
{
    $val = floatval(get_min_price());
    $sum = $val + $val;
    var_dump($sum);
    var_dump($val);
}
```

*Output*

```
float(1.20383)
float(0)
float(0)
```

**how to make a sum from a function?**

Comment: `1.20383` is in your output, so looks like it's doing what you want. And the other outputs you show are showing they are float (or double) data types. Are you wanting something else?

Comment: if you want the function changing to return a float then add the function's code to your question. You can also cast to a data type, like `$float = (float) $min;`

Comment: if it were float, I could mathematically summarize it to another variable `echo $test_float+$float; output: 1.1 `

Comment: @james I so, too, has tried, not helps

Comment: $float = 1.20383;
$test_float = 1.1;
var_dump(gettype($float), gettype($test_float));
`double` and `double`
$total = $float + $test_float;
var_dump(gettype($total));
`double`
var_dump($total);
`2.3038`

Comment: So this means your function is not returning a float. Casting the result to a float should work. If not then can you show your function code as that is possibly the problem

Comment: @james I update this page & add function output

Comment: Your output doesn't match the PHP code that is doing the output. You echo `$float` which shows the number, but then where does `string(6) "double"` come from? Forgetting cast etc for a second, what is the raw data type of `$min`? eg `var_dump(gettype($min));

Comment: `var_dump(gettype($min));` output: `1.20383string(6) "string"`

Comment: and what does this output `$min = (float) $min; var_dump(gettype($min));`

Comment: @James i insert `$min = (float) $min; var_dump(gettype($min));` output `string(6) "double"`

Answer (score 0):

i finded answer `return $fin;`

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
// get info about the request
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($data,true);
$c = array_map( function ($in){
    return  $in['ask']['c'];
}, $arr['candles']);
sort($c);
//echo 'Min is: '.current($c)."\n";
$fin = end($c);
return $fin;
```

Get function and calculate

```
    function pivoty()
{
    $val = floatval(get_min_price());
    $sum = $val + $val;
    var_dump($sum);
}
```

output: `float(2.40766)`